# AngularJS JavaScript Object to Json

Tags: angularjs, json

I have the following Json I want to POST.

```
{
"team": {
    "id": "1",
    "teamName": "TeamName",
},
"location": {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "LocationName",
},
"duration": 60
"dateTime": 949417200000,
```

}

In my AnguarJS controller I need to accept the form data and create this json dynamically to POST to a web service.

I can get it to work fin without nested json, but not when as above.

```
    var team = {
        "id": "1",
        "teamName": "TeamName",
    };

    var location = {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Name",
    };

    var entry = {
        "duration": "40",
        "dateTime": "949417200000",
        "team": + "\"{" + team + "}\"",
        "location": + "\"{" + location + "}\""
    };
```

Team and Location are null when converted as follows;

```
console.log(angular.toJson(entry));
```

Comment: What is `.."team": + [team]..` supposed to do? Inspect `entry` in `console.dir/log` to see "the problem".

Comment: Updated, as should of read "team": + "\"{" + angular.toJson(team) + "}\"", - team is NaN, without angular.toJson its null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't get why are you using `"team": + "\"{" + team + "}\"",` and `"location": + "\"{" + location + "}\""`, if you want to get the entire object in a JSON string, why don't yout just do:

```
var team = {
    "id": "1",
    "teamName": "TeamName",
};

var location = {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Name",
};

var entry = {
    "duration": "40",
    "dateTime": "949417200000",
    "team": team,
    "location": location
};

console.log( angular.toJson(entry) );
```

And try not to use `location` as a variable, because it can cause unwanted results due do `window.location` property.